# How to Close Statements and Connection in This Method

Tags: java, sqlite

How to Close Statements and Connection in This Method

```
public static ResultSet getData (String query){
    
    
    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.connect();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        
        return rs;
        
     
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.out.println(e);
        return null; 
    }
```

Comment: Did you read API documentation of Connection and Statement class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to close connections in `finally` block:

```
try {
...
}
catch {
...
}
finally {
  try { st.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* Ignored */ }
  try { con.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* Ignored */ }
}
```

In Java 7 and higher you can define all your connections and statements as a part of `try` block:

```
try(Connection con = ConnectionProvider.connect();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
) {

    // Statements
}
catch(....){}
```

Comment: `ResultSet` close statement removed, ty. `NullPointerException` must be catched in finally block nope?

Comment: You don't catch null pointer exceptions. You write code that doesn't throw them. The catch block is not needed unless you may throw exceptions unrelated to JDBC inside the block that you are thinking of handling.

Answer (score 0):

One should use *try-with-resources* to automatically close all.
Then there is the p

```
public static void processData (String query, Consumer<ResultSet> processor){
    try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.connect();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
         processor.accept(rs);      
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        System.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.Error, e);
    }
}

processData("SELECT * FROM USERS", rs -> System.out.println(rs.getString("NAME")));
```

Or

```
public static <T> List<T> getData (String query, UnaryOperator<ResultSet, T> convert){
    try (Connection con = ConnectionProvider.connect();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            result.add(convert.apply(rs));
        }
        return result;      
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.Error, e);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error in " + query, e);
    }
}
```

Then there is the danger with this function, that users will compose query strings like:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME = '" + name + "'";
```

Which does not escape the apostrophes like in `d'Alembert`. It opens the gates to **SQL injection**, a large security breach. One needs a PreparedStatement, and then can use type-safe parameters.

As with try-with-resources the code already is reduced (no explicit closes), you should drop this kind of function. But almost most programmers make this mistake.